# POSTing entities to WebAPI in batch?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Do I need to send individual entity updates to WebAPI, or can I POST an array of them and send them all at once?  It seems like a dumb question, but I can't find anything that says one way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brad has a blog [post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/batching-handler-for-web-api.html) that talks about implementing batching support in Web API.

Also, Web API samples [project](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) on codeplex has a [sample](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/13217b5b4cf1#Samples/Net45/CS/WebApi/HostedBatchSample/ReadMe.txt) for doing batching in web API hosted on asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like WEB API 2 has support for this

From the site (Web API Request Batching):

> Request batching is a useful way of minimizing the number of messages
>   that are passed between the client and the server. This reduces
>   network traffic and provides a smoother, less chatty user interface.
>   This feature will enable Web API users to batch multiple HTTP requests
>   and send them as a single HTTP request.

There are a number of samples for different scenarios on this page.

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web+API+Request+Batching

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an action that accepts a collection of items.

If all you have is an action that accepts a single item than you need to send separate requests.

With batching always think about how you would report the failures and whether a failing of a single item should invalidate the whole batch.

Comment: I wonder if it would be easier to queue the post requests on the client. Are there any examples of "batching" you can point me at? I'm not finding anything.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by 'queue the post requests on the client' and how this would help with the fact that you have multiple requests to start with and an action that accepts only one item.

Comment: I meant generate all of the requests on my client (iPad app), put them in a queue, and send them one at a time to the web service.  What little I found on batching looks relatively complicated.  Thanks for the help.